# Mounting .vdi image of a Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

Is there any way to mount the .vdi image that is running on a Virtual Box in the local drive.

Comment: Actually two same copies of the same .vdi are running on two different Virtual Box and i have to sync their home directory. So i was thinking of mounting the .vdi and then synchronizing the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/) explains how to mount VDI images using [qemu-nbd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/qemu-nbd.8.html), which exposes images as a Network Block Device. Note that this must **not** be done while the image is being used by a running VM. The following will mount the first partition of the image on `/mnt/myvm1`:

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 myvm.vdi
sudo mkdir /mnt/myvm1
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/myvm1
```